# RegEx for a string that may have a version at the beginning of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So, my program can accept strings like:

- `@vS050_A1_0002「Hello!」`
- `@v2124_A4_005「Bye, Bye」`
- `@k789_S3_100「Lorem imsum」`

and also a string without a version number:

- `Vivamus blandit et nibh nec placerat.`
- `In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti.`

I tried to write a regular expression to remove the version from the string. And it came out something like this: `^[^「]*`. It finds a match for the version and successfully replaces it with an empty string. But the problem is that it also works on strings without a version. That is, it deletes the entire line without the version.

So, my question is, how do I write a regular expression that only works with sentences that start with a version?

Example: A program receives 2 strings. The first `@vS050_A1_0002「Hello!」` and the second `Example2 string2`. The result after the regular expression should be `「Hello!」` and `Example2 string2`.

Comment: The regexp should begin with `^@`, so it shouldn't match anything in the last 2 examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^@\w+/
```

will match `@` followed by letters and numbers at the beginning of the string.

```js
const strings = [
  '@vS050_A1_0002「Hello! ',
  '@v2124_A4_005「Bye, Bye」',
  '@k789_S3_100「Lorem imsum」',
  'Vivamus blandit et nibh nec placerat.',
  'In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti.'
];

const reg = /^@\w+\s*/;

strings.forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(reg, '')));
```